# Help identifying what series this doll comes from

Tags: story-identification, character-identification

I've had this doll for a very long time (the past 10 years at least) and never known where it was from.  It seems to me that it is from some sci-fi series.  I never got the packaging, only the doll.  I've included a couple of pictures below:

[image: Wearing helmet]

[image: Without helmet]

The inscriptions on the back are as follows:

- Copyright 1990 Continuity Graphics
- Dist. by Hasbro Inc.
- Made in China

**I'm looking for who this character is and from what series or movie they are from.**

Answer (score 21, accepted):

That is [Bucky O'Hare](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bucky_O%27Hare) character Willy Duwitt.

> The storyline of Bucky O'Hare follows a parallel universe (the aniverse), where a war is ongoing between the slightly inept United Animals Federation (run by mammals) and the sinister Toad Empire. The Toad Empire is led by a vast computer system known as KOMPLEX, which has brainwashed the toad population.
>
> Willy DuWitt – engineer, a pre-teen human from San Francisco who enters the Aniverse via a portal between the ship's photon accelerator and his own accelerator at home. He replaced Bruce, the former engineer, who was killed (or in the franchise's terms, had "attained oneness with the Aniverse"). Later, Willy became stranded in the Aniverse when his parents turned off the photon accelerator back in his room. Bucky and his crew decide to keep Willy a secret from the S.P.A.C.E organization and the Toads.

[image]

The pilot episode is available on [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cgpfoobDjQU).

Comment: Wow - insanely fast response to a question that's plagued me for the better part of my life!  Great work!

Comment: @cde : I am thoroughly impressed with not only your speed (less than 4 mins) but also how completely you were able to answer the question in that short space of time.  Kudos!!  :-)

Comment: Just wondering why a kid would have an accelerator in his home...

Comment: @N_Soong - never heard of this guy: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Hahn ?

Comment: @HorusKol actually no!  Thanks for the link though - looks like an interesting read.  Wow - he was assigned to the *Enterprise* - incredible how everything relates back to Star Trek in some way ;)

Comment: @N_Soong Most kids have a photon accelerator https://c1.staticflickr.com/9/8363/8340185845_8456ff42bb.jpg